# GrandCentralDispatch big download queue eventually depletes memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have the current code to let a big list of files (about 6k images, about 2.8GB in size) for our Enterprise App.

At about 1.71GB transferred files (~660seconds) the memory obviously was depleted. I wonder what I can do to optimize:

**Queue:**

```
dispatch_queue_t imageQueue1 = dispatch_queue_create("Image Queue 1", NULL);
```

**Loop:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < [imgs count]; i++) {
    dispatch_async(imageQueue1, ^{
        NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", damPath, [imgs objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSString *savePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", newDir, [imgs objectAtIndex:i]];

        if (![data writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"Saving of \"%@\" failed!", [imgs objectAtIndex:i]);
        }

        NSString *progress = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d / %u downloaded...", i, [imgs count]];
        NSLog(@"%@", progress);
    });
}
```

I also wonder how I can multi-task these GCD queues. For my test I just copy-pasted this code 6 times, where `imageQueue#` increments and `[imgs count]` is a fixed offset, solely for testing purposes.

**Update**

The cap runs in jaw-like patterns to about caps of 38~MB:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @autoreleasepool to give the autoreleased memory a chance to drain:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [imgs count]; i++) {
    dispatch_async(imageQueue1, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", damPath, [imgs objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            NSString *savePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@", newDir, [imgs objectAtIndex:i]];

            if (![data writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES]) {
                NSLog(@"Saving of \"%@\" failed!", [imgs objectAtIndex:i]);
            }

            NSString *progress = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d / %u downloaded...", i, [imgs count]];
            NSLog(@"%@", progress);
        }
    });
}
```

Looking at the documentation, dispatch queues do provide autorelease pools, but there is no guarantee that they'll be drained, so for very memory intensive operations like this, you're probably well served by adding your own.

> if your block creates more than a few Objective-C objects, you might want to enclose parts of your block’s code in an @autorelease block to handle the memory management for those objects. Although GCD dispatch queues have their own autorelease pools, they make no guarantees as to when those pools are drained. If your application is memory constrained, creating your own autorelease pool allows you to free up the memory for autoreleased objects at more regular intervals

Comment: Thanks for the response David. I will try to do a few more runs to see if it matters. The first *big* run is the only important one. After that it's just small checks and syncs. The initial process can take 10-40 minutes; that's not really a problem. As long as the app doesn't crash :P. The offline buffer is needed for our agents to be able to have all product images with them when they don't have internet at our clients :)

Comment: Might you also know how I can dispatch multiple of these tasks (making `imageQueue#` dynamically spawn)? I don't really mind just hardcoding to a max of 10 queues, but it might be nice to tidy that code up with a simpler loop. Maybe it's possible to spawn the queues or put them in some kind of list/dict structure?

Comment: You can use a concurrent dispatch queue instead of a serial.  Pass `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` as the 2nd parameter to `dispatch_queue_create`

Comment: That will allow multiple operations to be executed concurrently.  How many are executed at a time will be determined by the system (basically # of cores, loading, battery state, and a lot of other issues can be considered)